# Modifying property of checkbox elements with respect to Django model data

Tags: django

### Problem

I have a django model named 'Task' which is related to a model called 'List' (A list has several tasks). I have appended all the 'Task' objects of all 'List' objects in an array 'tasks'. The Task object has a boolean member 'completed' which is true if the task is completed and false if not.

Now, in the template I want to iterate the array 'tasks' and find all those tasks which are completed and change the state of their check-boxes as 'checked' through their IDs (checkbox ID format : task). How do I do it?

### Code

I have tried the following django template code with JavaScript but its not working apparently.

```js
<script>
{% for list_tasks in tasks %}
    {% for task in list_tasks %}
        {% if task.completed == True %}
            document.getElementById("task{{task.id}}").checked=true;
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in JavaScript, you can directly do it in the html.

For example:

```
{% for list_tasks in tasks %}
    {% for task in list_tasks %}
        <input type="checkbox" {% if task.completed %} checked {% endif %} />
        <label for="task{{task.id}}"> Task name </label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if you update your question with how you display these checkboxes, I could help more.

Also, another option would be to create a form with dynamic firlds directly in django. This is a good article on how to do it: https://jacobian.org/2010/feb/28/dynamic-form-generation/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting dynamic forms Catalin :D . Also, is it just not possible to do that with JS?

Comment: Your code is not entirely wrong, did you check the source of the page to see if the JavaScript is what you want? Maybe your {{task.id}} outputs something different than what you have set to be the id of the checkbox input. You could try {{task.id|safe}} but I need to see more code to help you out.

Comment: That portion isn't there when I view source from browser.